"... && coverage report" not working after switching to pytest-django
I was using unittest in Django to write tests and running the tests with this command:
coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' src/manage.py test src && coverage report

It'd run the tests then display the .coverage generated by coverage run ... after running.
After installing pytest-django and setting up pytest.ini, I've updated my command to:
coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py' -m pytest && coverage report

Note, I'm not using pytest-cov just yet.
For some reason I can't figure out, the coverage report is not being displayed after the tests run.
I can run each commands separately:

The coverage run ... runs the tests and generates the report.
The coverage report displays the report.

I just can't get the report to display doing ... && coverage report after switching to pytest-django.
Any reason for this?
Versions:
coverage = "^6.2"
pytest-django = "^4.7.0"


Does coverage run ... succeed (exit 0)? If not then coverage report won't get reached.

Can you explain why you need to run them as one line? If they work as two separate commands, run them as two commands.

Why not just put the two commands in a script or batch file and call it good?

Per the comments, I ended up just making it two separate commands.
In my Dockerfile:
...
RUN coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py,*/migrations/*,*/apps.py' -m pytest -m=ut
RUN coverage report -m
...

And running in the containers with devspace:
...
      onUpload:
        exec:
          - command: |
              coverage run --omit='src/manage.py,src/config/*,*/.venv/*,*/*__init__.py,*/tests.py,*/admin.py,*/migrations/*,*/apps.py' -m pytest -m=ut
              coverage report -m
...

